# Xcode -dynamic not specified static library error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, build-error

I have a sub project within Xcode which creates a static library referenced by the parent project. All has been well until the release of iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1, suddenly I'm getting the following warning.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
```

Does anybody know what I need to do to fix this warning?

Comment: Same here. tried adding -dynamic flag, led to even more errors and warnings. I wish someone could add some insight into the depth of the problem. because it seems too fundamental to change flag lists from compiler version to another one.

Comment: Yep, I tried that too... Same problem. Also marking the dynamic library as optional has no effect. This was suggested as a solution on another forum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the solutions lies in the basic concept of dynamic and static libraries. as far as libraries go, dynamic libraries (libsqlite3.0.dylib in your case) are system libraries and you do not need to add them to your static library! all you need to do is to add their reference in your final **Target** you want to use them in (your application).

so, in short: Try removing the reference to `sqlite3.0.dylib` from your static library (I'm guessing another project you are using inside your top level application) and add it to your application (not static library) and you're probably good to go. (solved my problem)

[Edit]:
please commit your project's git or do whatever you do to make a backup from your project, there is a chance that Xcode may break your project with no reason after removing these dynamic libraries and NO, deleting project's **Derived data** won't solve the problem.

Comment: I'll give this a try, however in my case the project which builds my static library needs to be compilable on it's own, i.e. even when it's not contained within another project. If i remove the dynamic sqlite library from it, this will break.

Comment: That's kindda odd don't you think? if your project is static how could it be standalone only? I mean your bundle type is either a library (static or dynamic) or Executable, am I right? if it is a library, there will always be another project to use it and it should have the reference to the dynamic libraries we were talking about. give it a try, it solved my problem just to lead me to an even more annoying problem ugh. :(

Comment: Oh sure, and the library will still work within those projects. But the static library project itself is setup in its own CI system in a code management system. It also gets distributed to third parties as a compiled binary, so we need to be able to build it on it's own. Although i suppose we could create a dummy container project for it, just seems a bit of a weird workaround!

Comment: Marked your answer as correct because it does appear to be the solution, I still think this is a weird change for Apple to make in a .1 release!

Comment: couldn't agree more @Sammio2!

Comment: @M.Porooshani You said "add it to your application (not static library"- what does that mean? Where specifically in Xcode do you add the library? "Add it to your application" is incredibly vague and unhelpful.

Comment: @autibyte, I'm sorry you didn't get it, But please do read the answer one more time (especially the parentheses) . and Thanks for the down vote!

Comment: @M.Porooshani Anytime. Just read through it again, and it still isn't clear that what's needed is to remove the dynamic library from "Link Binary with Libraries" and to add it as a dynamic flag to the root level application.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me. He has two projects, one an iOS application and the other a static library. The iOS application depends on the static library. You shouldn't link a dynamic library with the static library project but with the iOS application project instead.