# libsqlite3.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, build-error

I've updated the project from xCode 4 to xCode 5.1. And now I get the following error on build:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
> **-dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC**
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
> file:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/**libsqlite3.dylib**
> **is a dynamic library, not added to the static library**

How can I fix it? I've tried to find any special build parameters (including -ObjC) but all of them are standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is similar to the duplicated question [Xcode -dynamic not specified static library error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320911/xcode-dynamic-not-specified-static-library-error?rq=1) :

Just remove `libsqlite3.dylib` from the own static library on the project.